# Calling cross account AWS EC2 instance Lambda function not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I setup a Lambda function using Node.js that will pass an instance id and then start that instance by calling "ec2.startInstances".

- I hard coded the "accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, and region" inside
  the function.
- I tested the "Node.js" code locally on my laptop, and it starts the
  instance just fine.
- I tested the Lambda function in the account where the instance resides, and it starts just fine.
- I then tested the Lambda function from a different AWS account, where the AWS instance does not exist, and I receive an error saying it can't find the instance id.

I am confused why the Lambda function cares what account it is currently executing on, especially WHEN I am declaring the correct accesskeyid, secretaccesskey, and region to the account that DOES have the instance I am specifying.

The use case here is to have a master account, with a lambda function, that can call a start or stop of instances that DO NOT reside on the master account.

I have read and seen some examples of how you can do this by specifying correct IAM roles and permissions on Account A and Account B, etc.. However, this solution becomes tedious when you have hundreds or thousands of accounts.

***I am really looking for a way to use Lambda the same way I use the AWS SDK locally on my laptop through node.js, or powershell, etc. I just dont understand why specifying the credentials for the other account is NOT ENOUGH for Lambda???***

Here is the code I am using:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var instanceId = event.instanceid;
    AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
    AWS.config.accessKeyId = "accesskey";
    AWS.config.secretAccessKey = "secretkey";
    AWS.config.region = "us-west-2";

    var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();

    console.log('instanceid:' + instanceId);

    var params = {
      InstanceIds: [ 'i-sdakuyvsdx' ]
    };
    ec2.startInstances(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) { context.fail(err); } 
      else { context.succeed(instanceId + ' successfully started.'); }           
    });
};
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> "errorMessage": "The instance ID 'i-sdakuyvsdx' does not exist",
>     "errorType": "InvalidInstanceID.NotFound",